# Return two values from for loop in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to return two values from the array with the for loop, but am only getting the first value instead.

```
data class Batches(
    var qty: Int?,
    var entries: List<TruckEntry>?,
    var entryIds: ArrayList<String>?,
    var priceconfig: PriceConfig?

) {
    constructor() : this(0, null, null, null)
}

data class TruckEntry(var name: String?, var id: String?, var qty: Int?, var observed: Int?) {
    constructor() : this(null, null, null, null)
}
```

My function:

```
private fun getBatchName(batches: Batches): String? {
                  if (!batches.entries.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    val entrySize = arrayOf(batches.entries!!)
                    for(index in 0..entrySize.size - 1){
                        return batches.entries!![index].name
                    }
                }
                      return "****************"

    }
```

Comment: Yes, this is how loops work. `return` exits the function with the value that comes after it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Like my question is as what to implement in order to return the two values in the array instead of only one value.

Comment: You could return a `Pair`

Comment: @FrancisGacheru What are the two values you want to return? The first two names in _batches.entries_, or the list of all these names plus something else (which would be what? the list of the ids?)?

Comment: @lukas.j I want to return one name if there is only one name in batches.entries but if I have two names in batches.entries it returns the two names. But with my function, it is only returning one name even when I have two names in batches.entries.

Comment: @FrancisGacheru: and what if there are three or more? Your _var entries_ is a List.

Comment: @lukas.j From the Backend API I have restricted to have a maximum of two entries.

Comment: @FrancisGacheru But it then not make more sense to reflect that in the design of the _Batches_ class. For example by replacing _entries_ with _entry1: TruckEntry_ and _entry2: ..._? Or by using a _Pair<TruckEntry>_?

Comment: Just for advice. If you want default values no need to describe constructor. In Kotlin you can do somthn like that `data class TruckEntry(var name: String? = null, var id: String? = null, var qty: Int? = null, var observed: Int? = null)`

Comment: @EnzyWeiss I appreciate. Already working on that.

Answer (score 1):

Return always exits the function with a value or null. You need to store the value found inside the loop in a variable and return it at the end of the function with the other value you want.

I'm not a kotlin programmer, so here is a pseudo code which might help you.

```
//A class that will hold your return values
//as you can only return one value from a function once

class Holder{
  constructor(data1, data2){
    this.returnValue1 = data1
    this.returnValue2 = data2
  }
}
```

```
function yourFunction(batches){
  var data1
  var data2 = "whatever"
  
  for( batch in batches ){
    if( condition ){
      data1 = batch
      break
    }
  }

  return new Holder(data1, data2)
}
```

Also when accessing this values from another functions/classes you need to access these according to your `Holder class`. Like

```
var returnVal = yourFunction(batches)
var val1 = returnVal.returnValue1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return more than one thing from a function, you need to return something that can hold multiple values, such as a Pair, Triple, or List. List makes the most sense in this case since you don't know for sure how many values there will be.

Example:

```
private fun getBatchNames(batches: Batches): List<String?> {
    return batches.entries.orEmpty()
        .map { it.name }
}
```